# Directly asking questions about adjective complements

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives, complements

Can we ask some questions about adjective complements?

> I was disappointed with your behaviour.(1)

Can we ask its question like

> With what were you disappointed? (2)

or

> What were you disappointed with? (3)

---

> I am good at math and physics. (4)

Can we ask its question like?

> At what areas are you good? (5)

or

> What areas are you good at? (6)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the first section (3) is idiomatic.

> What were you disappointed with? (3)

In the second section

> At what areas are you good? (5)
>
> What areas are you good at? (6)

would be better as

> Which subjects are you good at?
>
> Which are your best subjects?

Comment: It seems that you didn't specify your opinion about (2) , what do you think about it? In my opinion, it is very formal but grammatically correct.

Comment: I implied that (2) was inferior, though correct. It is stilted.

Comment: Do you have any reason for that?

Comment: Only because I am a native speaker. (2) is used sometimes, such as in the song "There's a hole in my bucket" where a line says "With what shall I mend it, dear Liza, dear Liza".

Comment: I see. In terms of grammaticality, there is no problem but it doesn't sound natural.

Comment: @Jawel Yes, it's grammatical, but pied-piping of prepositions is generally confined to formal style. 2 and 5 would therefore sound somewhat stilted (2 more than 5) in normal conversation.

Comment: (But, of course, 5 is again not very idiomatic for other reasons implied in the answer.)